# How can I clear the iis cache on Microsoft Azure Server?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-8, octopus-deploy

I am a web developer of a small software company.

We are using Octopus for the web source deployment to the Microsoft Azure Server.

A few days ago, I deployed the latest commit of prod source to Azure via Octopus successfully.

And I've made change of small code to the web source directly in Azure.

But unexpectedly, my chrome is still working for the old version and modified source is not working.

I think it is an issue from cache of IIS or Azure.

How can I clear the cache for IIS or Azure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By reading your question, first we need to determine the root cause of the problem.**

After below steps, you can solve the issues.

---

*1. First, check the following two options in the browser.*

[image]

*2. Refresh the page and check whether it is updated to the latest webapp.*

*3. If yes, you don't need to refresh your azure webapp. If not, we need to further check the cause of the problem.*

*4. Go to scm site, and check the source file to see if the program is successfully deployed. You also can download it and deploy it in your local to check.*

*5. If there is no problem with publishing the file, then we need to clear the cache for Azure at this time.*

[image]

Or you also can recyle your application by kill w3wp.exe.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, Jason. But, I don't think it is working correct for me. I just killed w3wp.exe on Task Manager but the script remains old version. In more detail, I modified some codes in javascript file on Azure server directly.

Comment: @JaimeLashley Pls modify your file name in your code with add `?v=`. Like `<script src="./index.js?v=20210906"></script>`.

Comment: I did it already but it worked at the very first time. The other is as same as old version.

Comment: @JaimeLashley Please use the privacy mode of your browser to access and test.

Comment: Yes, it is working for me now in incognito mode. Thanks but how can it work correctly in normal mode of browser?

Comment: @JaimeLashley Normally, if you modify the js file directly on the server, you need to add a timestamp to the referenced web page.

Comment: @JaimeLashley The privacy mode just now and my first suggestion at the beginning are to refresh the web page and clear the previous cache.

Comment: @JaimeLashley Generally you can modify your code like me to refresh the cache. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmaAD.png  It is not recommended to use in a production environment, and it is also not recommended to modify files directly in a production environment.

Comment: that is also working for me in normal mode. thanks for your help.